# "Stack limit reached 1024 (1023)" Error

Tags: solidity, mapping, brownie

as you can see in the title, I have the following problem:
I have two different types of NFTs in the same contract and I wanted to make transactions way cheaper using a single mapping for knowing the exact minted amount of each one and the type of NFT (for example if NFT number n is of the first or second type).
Everything works well until I try to execute the minting function a second time.
In fact, the first time I try to mint, no errors are shown and every variable is updated correctly.
The second time I try to call the same function it shows this error: "stack limit reached 1024 (1023)".

The code is the following with pragma solidity ^0.8.0:

```
function mintSKN(uint amount) public payable{
    require(contractOnline, "You must wait before buying those keys");
    require(amount > 0, "The amount must be greater than zero");
    require(getNormalMinted() + amount < normalMintLimit, "Normal Keys were sold out!");
    require(normalBalanceOf(msg.sender) + amount < maximumNormalForAddress, "You cannot buy this amount of keys!");
    require(msg.value >= normalPrice * amount, "You must specify a greater amount!");
    _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    tokens[tokenSupply - 1] = 1;
}
```

The error seems to be occurring with the last line of code, where I try to add the last token minted to a mapping (uint => uint) called tokens with the value 1.
I'm pretty sure about that because without this line everything works everytime I call the function.

Thank you in advantage!

Edit:
Every variable is given through the constructor. This is the interested part of the smart contract:

```
contract SoulKey is ERC721_bys{
// Are Soul Keys setContractOnline?
bool private contractOnline;
// Token utils
mapping(uint => uint) private tokens;
// Mint limit for addresses
uint private maximumNormalForAddress;
uint private maximumOpForAddress;
// Keys mint limits
uint private normalMintLimit;
uint private opMintLimit;
// Events
event SoulContractOnline(bool _newStatus);
// When a contract is created it has not a soulContract associated nor a contractOnline = true status
// Mint functions
function mintSKN(uint amount) public payable{
    require(contractOnline, "You must wait before buying those keys");
    require(amount > 0, "The amount must be greater than zero");
    require(getNormalMinted() + amount < normalMintLimit, "Normal Keys were sold out!");
    require(normalBalanceOf(msg.sender) + amount < maximumNormalForAddress, "You cannot buy this amount of keys!");
    require(msg.value >= normalPrice * amount, "You must specify a greater amount!");
    _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    // tokens[tokenSupply] = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, "/", BYS_Utils(utils).toString(normalMinted), "_normal.json"));
    tokens[tokenSupply - 1] = 1;
}
function mintSKOP(uint amount) public payable{
    require(contractOnline, "You must wait before buying those keys");
    require(amount > 0, "The amount must be greater than zero");
    require(getOpMinted() + amount < opMintLimit, "OP Keys were sold out!");
    require(opBalanceOf(msg.sender) + amount < maximumOpForAddress, "You cannot buy this amount of keys!");
    require(msg.value >= opPrice * amount, "You must specify a greater amount!");
    _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    // tokens[tokenSupply] = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, "/", BYS_Utils(utils).toString(opMinted), "_op.json"));
    tokens[tokenSupply - 1] = 2;
}
// Is the key specified a normal or an op one?
/*
    1  = Normal
    2  = Op
    0 = Error
*/
function keyType(uint _tokenId) public view returns (uint){
    require(_tokenId < tokenSupply, "The specified token does not exists!");
    for(uint i = _tokenId; i < tokenSupply; i++){
        if(tokens[_tokenId] == 1){
            return 1;
        }else if(tokens[_tokenId] == 2){
            return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
// Getters
function getNormalMinted() public view returns (uint){
    uint normalMinted;
    uint currentMinted;
    for(uint i; i < tokenSupply; i++){
        currentMinted++;
        if(tokens[i] != 0){
            if(tokens[i] == 1){
                normalMinted += currentMinted;
            }
            currentMinted = 0;
        }
    }
    return normalMinted;
}
function getOpMinted() public view returns (uint){
    uint opMinted;
    uint currentMinted;
    for(uint i; i < tokenSupply; i++){
        currentMinted++;
        if(tokens[i] != 0){
            if(tokens[i] == 2){
                opMinted += currentMinted;
            }
            currentMinted = 0;
        }
    }
    return opMinted;
}
function normalBalanceOf(address _address) public view returns (uint){
    uint balance;
    for(uint i; i < tokenSupply; i++){
        if(tokens[i] == 1 && ownerOf(i) == _address){
            balance++;
        }
    }
    return balance;
}
function opBalanceOf(address _address) public view returns (uint){
    uint balance;
    for(uint i; i < tokenSupply; i++){
        if(tokens[i] == 2 && ownerOf(i) == _address){
            balance++;
        }
    }
    return balance;
}
}
```

You can take a look at the ERC721_bys code here: https://github.com/BYS-Project/Common/blob/main/Contracts/ERC721_bys.sol

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a loop because the function `OwnerOf()` was calling the function `_exists()` that calls again `OwnerOf()`.
That was it!